# Retrieve local JSON file data in EJS template

Tags: javascript, ejs

My project looks like this:

```
views/
    layout.ejs
data/
    US-states.json
public/
    index.html
```

US-states.json looks like this

```
{
    "DC": "District of Colombia",
    "NY": "New York",
    etc...
}
```

How can I pull this json data into `layout.ejs` to render some divs in a loop like this?

```
<div>DC: District of Colombia</div>
<div>NY: New York</div>
```

I tried something like this but I'm having trouble googling the solution:

```
var data = JSON.parse('./../data/US-states.json')
<% for(var p in data) {%>
   <div>p: data[p]</div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Your template should not be responsible for getting files!

Comment: @Mathletics this abstracted example isn't 100% reflective of the project I'm working on; I need to import data into this component which is then required by a main layout file. Regardless, I'm not fluent in EJS best practices.

Comment: I think this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and I agree with @Eleanore's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not retrieve data from the view. Thus, when you have retrieved it in the backend, you pass the JavaScript object representing your data (as the one you cited in your question) to the EJS from the business layer. I do not know what you are using as a backend framework. For instance, when using NodeJS:

```
response.render("yourEJS", {data: yourObject});
```

Then, in your view, you traverse the object via JavaScript:

```
<% for (aProperty in data) { %>
    <div> <% aProperty %>: <%data[aProperty]%> </div>
<% } %>
```